# react-native ruby/cocoapods issue

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods, npx

I've already developed an app using react-native in my development environment. This app is currently working normally without any problems.

I'm asking because I'm having trouble creating a new project because I need to develop a new app.

It was the react-native 0.72.3 version, but when I ran the "npx react-native init myApp" command, I was asked to install 0.73.0, so I installed it. Since then, installation has become normal, but there was a version problem when I installed the amplify-related package, so I deleted the app and re-executed the "npx react-native init myApp" command, which started the problem. (I used the --version="0.72.3" option because of the amplify-related package.)

I also erased the cache and reinstalled it several times, but the same error persisted.

The error is as shown in the image below.

[image]

I went to the link mentioned in the error message and checked it, and it's all already set up. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=ios&guide=native)

I am using M1 MacBook and the version of ruby and cocoapods are as follows.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]

$ pod --version
1.14.3
```

I tried Googling, but I couldn't find a way. I'm very new to React Native development. If anyone has solutions, I'd greatly appreciate detailed explanations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the command when creating the project. If you create the project as below, there is no problem.

> npx react-native@x.xx.x init myApp --version x.xx.x